# Importing font variant in scss - React

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, google-fonts

I'm new to `css` so I'm a little confused. Here is what I'm doing in my `index.scss` file

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:400,400i,700,800,800i,900i&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

I want to make all the paragraphs `Nunito Sans Bold Italic`. How can I do that in a specific file say `components/link.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make all paragraphs styled with Nunito Sans in bold and italic, you first need to target every `p` element, then add the font-family and the font styles you need. For example:

```
p {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

If you only want this css in that particular component, create a separate scss file and import it only into that component, for example:

`@import './link-style.scss';`

Answer (score 0):

This may work

```css
//index.scss

.paragraph {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<!--Link js -->
<p className="paragraph">
paragraph text
</p>
```